# Will removing an SSH key during an active session kick me out of the session?

Tags: ssh, smartcard

I am carrying my SSH key in a [NitroKey](https://nitrokey.com) smartcard, meaning that in order to SSH into a remote server, I first have to plug in the NitroKey so the local computer can read the private key.

However, I am wondering if I need to keep the private key available (i.e. keep the NitroKey plugged in) even after I've already established an active session? Does SSH continuously check whether the SSH private key is present during an active session? Or does it only check when connecting, and never afterwards? (meaning that I can remove the NitroKey without risking the session being interrupted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical USB key is only ever needed when the private key is needed, which is only when you make the initial connection to an SSH server, at least under normal circumstances.